# Creating lambda log subscription with serverless

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy some lambdas via serverless and along with deploying the lambda I want to also set up a log subscription for said lambda. I'm trying to use the 'serverless-plugin-log-subscription' in my serverless yml file. When I try to run the serverless file I get the below error in my github workflow.

```
An error occurred: UserDashsettingsLogLambdaPermission - Properties validation failed for resource UserDashsettingsLogLambdaPermission with message:
  #/FunctionName: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern].
```

Below is my serverless.yml file that I am using. Not sure why I'm getting that error when the file is running. I looked at this documentation 'https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-log-subscription' for reference.

```
service: app-operations
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326

custom:
  myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  alerts:
    nameTemplate: ${self:custom.myStage}-$[functionName]-errors
    prefixTemplate: ${ssm:/orbit/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/ALARM_PREFIX}
    topics:
      ok:
        topic: ${ssm:/orbit/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/ALERTS_TOPIC_ARN}
      alarm:
        topic: ${ssm:/orbit/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/ALERTS_TOPIC_ARN}
    definitions:
      functionErrors:
        threshold: 5
        evaluationPeriods: 5
        datapointsToAlarm: 5
        treatMissingData: notBreaching
    alarms:
      - functionErrors


plugins:
  # - serverless-jetpack
  # - serverless-plugin-aws-alerts
  # - serverless-offline
  - serverless-plugin-log-subscription

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20200924
  # profile: app-${file(./configs/${self:custom.myStage}-config.json):PROFILE}
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - app-ops-api-key-${self:custom.myStage}
  stackTags:
    PLATFORM: APP
  environment:
    SNS_TOPIC_NAME: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/SNS_TOPIC_NAME}
    WORKSPACE: ${ssm:/app/shared/WORKSPACE}
    WRAPPING: ${ssm:/app/shared/WRAPPING}
    BUSY: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/BUSY}
    OFFLINE: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/OFFLINE}
    WF_QUEUE_LAMBDA_NAME: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/WF_QUEUE_LAMBDA_NAME}
    WF_GLOBAL_LAMBDA_NAME: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/WF_GLOBAL_LAMBDA_NAME}
    ES_ENDPOINT: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/ES_ENDPOINT}
    INDEX_PREFIX: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/INDEX_PREFIX}
    BACKEND_API_URL: ${ssm:/app/shared/${self:custom.myStage}/BACKEND_API_URL}
    BACKEND_API_KEY: ${ssm:/app/shared/${self:custom.myStage}/BACKEND_API_KEY}
    API_KEY_SECRET_ID: ${ssm:/app/shared/API_KEY_SECRET_ID}
    SECRET_UID: ${ssm:/app/shared/SECRET_UID}
    USER_SETTINGS_TABLE: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/USER_SETTINGS_TABLE}
    SLEEP_IN_MS: ${ssm:/app/operations/${self:custom.myStage}/SLEEP_IN_MS}

  role:
    Fn::GetAtt:
      - LambdaRole
      - Arn

functions:
  user-settings:
    handler: user-settings.handler
    description: get user settings
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: app/user-settings
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
    logSubscription:
      enabled: true
      destinationArn: arn:aws:lambda:${ssm:/app/shared/region}:$file{(./configs/${self:custom.myStage}-config.json):AWSAccount}:function:LoggingLambda:WORK
      filterPattern: ""
```

Comment: Could you try not using `-` in the function name? I think it might be an issue there